# After android update 6.0 on my sony xperia Z5 compact i can no longer get passed the lock screen

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I go to put in my pin and then the screen goes blank. It then returns back to the lock screen. Sometimes it says system UI has stopped. I have restarted it many times, put into safe mode, turned it off from the off button beside the SIM...Can anyone tell me what to do please.

Comment: Can you consider [tag:factory-reset] here? It will wipe the data but so as remove that lock.

Comment: how to i factory reset a phone when i cant get into settings

Comment: Follow this: http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info